# Accusative in the first position

Tags: grammar-identification

Knowing very little German I remember learning about how German word order is a bit like boxes where every "box" can be moved in different positions when and where appropriate.

One sentence that I was reading today was

> Einen blauen Fleck bekommt man schnell

In this sentence I can see that the verb bekommt is clearly second, but the subject and the "direct object" or I like to say *the thing that is affected* have swapped places.

Is this allowed in German?

Comment: If you mean _"Man bekommt schnell einen blauen Fleck."_ This kind of swapping is legit and allowed, yes.

Answer (score 3):

The categories *direct object* and *indirect object* will only confuse you when it comes to German. Forget about them and think about accusative, dative, genitive objects.

---

Word order in declarative sentences in German pivots around the fact the conjugated verb always comes second. This becomes clear to English speakers as soon English *topicalization* is involved:

> Im Sommer **fahren wir** ans Meer.

*In summer **we go** to the seaside.*

By this simple example without any object at all, you can already see an important difference between German and English word order. In English, the subject **always precedes** the conjugated verb, while in German, there is **only ever one item in front of** the conjugated verb.

German declarative sentences have their topic always in front. And this item may be anything. The subject. An object. An adverbial. A list. A whole clause. Whatever is in front of the conjugated verb is **one single item**. And the topic. That's the whole idea.

Answer (score 2):

German is indeed pretty flexible with regards to word order - Subject and object(s) can swap places, the only condition that must be met is: The verb must be in position 2.

The following sentences are all valid German sentences (although the meaning is  different depending on the overall position of the adverbial) - Not all possible permutations listed:

- Man fängt am besten Elefanten mit Mausefallen
- Elefanten fängt man am besten mit Mausefallen
- Am besten fängt man Elefanten mit Mausefallen
- Mit Mausefallen fängt man am besten Elefanten
- Mit Mausefallen fängt man Elefanten am besten
- ...